# Oracle parameters in c# inline query with wildcard

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I am having trouble using parameters for my in line oraclae query in c#. Why does the parameter not work within the wildcard?

This line returns no results:

```
Select id, name from Users where UPPER(name) like '%:name%'
command.Parameters.Add("name", OracleDbType.Varchar2, name.ToUpper(), ParameterDirection.Input);
```

But this returns:

```
Select id, name from Users where UPPER(name) like '%" + name.ToUpper() +"%'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730941/how-to-use-wildcards-in-sql-query-with-parameters Check there, see if that answers your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean this?

```
Select id, name 
from Users 
where UPPER(name) like '%' ||:name.ToUpper()||'%'
```

This concatenates your C# variable and the Oracle wildcard characters.