# Trying to query contains search in golang with Prepare

Tags: sql, go

I have a prepare and a query function in go and when I place the ? in the search it works fine. When I try and do a contains search with the % I get `sql: statement expects 0 inputs; got 1`

How can I do this type of query without having the variables directly in the SQL? I want to prevent SQL injection . Thank You for your help.

I am using go version go1.8.1 darwin/amd64 and using MySQL

My Go Code:

```
stmt, err := dBusers.Prepare("SELECT id, name, email, username FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%?%';")
    if err != nil {
        logging.LogError("Could Not Query All Users: "+err.Error())
        return nil, errors.New("Could Not Query Users")
    }
    rows, err := stmt.Query(name)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730941/how-to-use-wildcards-in-sql-query-with-parameters suggests making your parameter argument (in this case, `name`) include the wildcards instead of the query.  So `stmt.Query("%" + name + "%")`.  This still prevents injection, because it's still being sent as a parameter instead of inline with the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reposting my comment as an answer so this question actually has one:

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730941/how-to-use-wildcards-in-sql-query-with-parameters) suggests making your parameter argument (in this case, `name`) include the wildcards instead of the query. So `stmt.Query("%" + name + "%")`. This still prevents injection, because it's still being sent as a parameter instead of inline with the query.

Answer (score 0):

You could either make the whole %searchValue% a parameter value itself, or use string concatenation for it inside the query itself.

Approach 1 (recommended):

```
stmt, err := dBusers.Prepare("SELECT id, name, email, username FROM users WHERE name LIKE ?;")
    if err != nil {
        logging.LogError("Could Not Query All Users: "+err.Error())
        return nil, errors.New("Could Not Query Users")
    }
    rows, err := stmt.Query("%" + name + "%")
```

Approach 2:

```
stmt, err := dBusers.Prepare("SELECT id, name, email, username FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%' + ? + '%';")
    if err != nil {
        logging.LogError("Could Not Query All Users: "+err.Error())
        return nil, errors.New("Could Not Query Users")
    }
    rows, err := stmt.Query(name)
```

I would recommend the first approach because it wouldn't force you to always use a "contains' search. You could selectively use the same statement to do exact (just name), begins with (name+"%"), ends with ("%"+name) or contains ("%"+name+"%") searches.

PS: Thinking about it, the second approach might lead to injection, not sure, need to think about it more.